# Python binding for Clipper

Tags: python, polygon, offset

Is there some Python binding for [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) library?
I need OffsetPolygons function. I've tried to convert C++ Clipper code to Python, and I managed to do that up to some point, but then it becomes too complex - and it seems that I should convert to Python complete Clipper file - which is huge job.

Some simple code for polygon borders offsetting with Python is available [here](http://pyright.blogspot.com/2011/07/pyeuclid-vector-math-and-polygon-offset.html), but it doesn't solve the problem universally - when offset distances are high and some corners disappear or new ones appear.

Any suggestions to other Python based solutions for polygon offsetting are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [pyclipper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyclipper) ([source](https://github.com/greginvm/pyclipper)) - it is a wrapper around the C++ version of the Clipper library (v6.2.1). It exposes all of Clippers' public methods. Installation via pip:

```
pip install pyclipper
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no Python binding for Clipper. To avoid the understandably daunting task of translation, my suggestion is to create a .dll or .so file that exports the OffsetPolygons function.

Answer (score 0):

[Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/index.html) implements a parallel_offset procedure that does what you want, and offers easy python/numpy integration: http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.parallel_offset